# How has IPS been affected by the current pandemic?

Tags: discussion, statistics

Did the current pandemic had an impact on traffic and posting on IPS? If so, how?

Answer (score 4):

Starting around the 9th of March 2020, it seems that the current pandemic did, indeed have a significant impact on IPS. More specifically on the number of questions and answers posted.

### Here are the data for IPS Main:

[image: Number of post on IPS main]

[image: Number of votes on IPS main]

[image: Traffic on IPS main]

### And here are the data for IPS Meta:

[image: Number of post on IPS Meta]

[image: Number of votes on IPS Meta]

[image: Traffic on IPS Meta]

### Conclusions

From those data we can clearly see that the number of posts posted has seen a significant drop. We have more or less two times less questions/answers being posted each week on IPS main. As for IPS meta, it's even worse. Since the "beginning" of the pandemic (let's say it was the 9th of March), we only had 5 questions asked. It's not even one per month.

As could be expected, the number of votes also decreased significatively on both main and meta (if there are fewer things posted, there are fewer new content to vote on).

The number of pages viewed (on both sites) decreased as well. However, (thankfully) the number of visits and new visits on main remained more or less steady.

Comment: You may want to make the meta plots weekly as well to make them less noisy.

Comment: "the current pandemic did, indeed have a significant impact on IPS" just nitpicking here, but correlation does not mean causation ;) chances are the pandemic is the main cause to blame, but we don't have tangible proof. I should look at IPS' sister sites stats because I have a gut feeling we're pretty much all in the same boat.

Comment: @avazula I don't like you, you are right >< If you want to know more about how other sites were affected, you can read this main meta question: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346812/400547

Comment: @avazula I edited to add an "it seems" at the beginning. Thanks for pointing it out :)